# Regex Comment Conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue with my regex. There is a "//" within the regex which has obviously broken the rest of my code...
It's a website verifier and this is by far the best regex I've found for it but MVC is being a pain!

```
function CheckWeb() {
    if ($("#Company_ContactType").val() == 'WEB') {
        if (/_^(?:(?:https?|ftp):/ / )( ? : \S + ( ? ::\S * ) ? @ @) ? ( ? : ( ? !10( ? : \.\d { 1, 3 }) { 3 })( ? !127( ? : \.\d { 1, 3 }) { 3 })( ? !169\ .254( ? : \.\d { 1, 3 }) { 2 })( ? !192\ .168( ? : \.\d { 1, 3 }) { 2 })( ? !172\.( ? : 1[6 - 9] | 2\ d | 3[0 - 1])( ? : \.\d { 1, 3 }) { 2 })( ? : [1 - 9]\ d ? | 1\ d\ d | 2[01]\ d | 22[0 - 3])( ? : \.( ? : 1 ? \d { 1, 2 } | 2[0 - 4]\ d | 25[0 - 5])) { 2 }( ? : \.( ? : [1 - 9]\ d ? | 1\ d\ d | 2[0 - 4]\ d | 25[0 - 4])) | ( ? : ( ? : [a - z\ x { 00 a1 } - \x { ffff } 0 - 9] + - ? ) * [a - z\ x { 00 a1 } - \x { ffff } 0 - 9] + )( ? : \.( ? : [a - z\ x { 00 a1 } - \x { ffff } 0 - 9] + - ? ) * [a - z\ x { 00 a1 } - \x { ffff } 0 - 9] + ) * ( ? : \.( ? : [a - z\ x { 00 a1 } - \x { ffff }] { 2, })))( ? ::\d { 2, 5 }) ? ( ? : /[^\s]*)?$_iuS/.test) {
            var resultDiv = $("#IsValid");
            resultDiv.text("");
        }
    });
}
```

is there any way for me to ensure that it doesn't comment out beyond the "test?

Comment: Why use a PCRE regex in JS?

Comment: Well honestly i don't know much about regex so I just used that one because it was the most comprehesive but beyond that i have no idea...

Comment: use backslash before every `/`. like.. `\/\/`

Comment: thank you! that helped... but now its breaking somewhere else...\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp):/ / )
```

Should look like:

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/ )
```

You also have another forward slash toward the end that needs escaped:

```
( ? : /[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

Should be:

```
( ? : \/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

This results in no pattern errors on regex101

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help!